# android expansion file update

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I have published a apk but now I want to change few images in expansion file, is there any way to update only expansion file without uploading new apk ? If yes what about users already downloaded app with old expansion ?

Answer (score 1):

It's very well [documented in the long description on Android Developers guides](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).

**To summarize**.

You always need to update the application code in order for the new expansion files being downloaded. You got a `patch` and a `main` expansion file. If you make any update to either your users have to download **whole** the updated file. So if you can stick with only updating the `patch` with some minor stuff your doing good and your users will only download the new `patch` file and the old `main` will stay with your users unspoiled.